# JQuery Ajax with Callbacks and Frame.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I need to execute several jquery Ajax calls sequentially. I'm using callbacks, so every call has a success function that execute the next Ajax call and so on.
That was really a mess and very difficult code to read. After googling a find Frame.js that looks awesome but... i can't make it work.

To simplify the problem I'm just trying to call the first web service and I'm doing this:

File: MyPage.aspx:

```
Frame(function (next) {
    this.request = { CodSeguro: 917766 };
        Emision_ConsultarSeguro(request, next, next);
        next();
    });
    Frame(function (next,ajaxResponse) 
    {
        alert(ajaxResponse);
    });
```

File: WebServices.js:

```
function Emision_ConsultarSeguro(requestData, okFunction, failFunction) 
{
    runAjax("Emision/emision.asmx/Consultar", request, okFunction, failFunction);
}
```

File: Common.js

```
function runAjax(url, request, okFunction, failFunction) 
{
    var dto = "{'request':" + JSON.stringify(request) + "}";
    execAjax(url, dto, okFunction, failFunction);
}
```

File: Ajax.js

```
function execAjax(url, data, successFunction, errorFunction) 
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetUrl() + url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
            successFunction(data); 
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown {
            errorFunction(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown); 
        }
    });
}
```

The Ajax calls is executed, but ajaxResponse is always undefined!!! Help please!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like under WebServices.js, you should replace your request argument with requestData.

```
function Emision_ConsultarSeguro(requestData, okFunction, failFunction) 
{
    runAjax("Emision/emision.asmx/Consultar", requestData, okFunction, failFunction);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i copy paste here the wrong code, in my webservices.js the correct variable name is used, so thats not the problem.